# Getting XQuery [modify()]: Top-level attribute nodes are not supported error while modifying xml

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005, t-sql

```
DECLARE @mycur CURSOR
DECLARE @id int
DECLARE @ParentNodeName varchar(max)
DECLARE @NodeName varchar(max)
DECLARE @NodeText varchar(max)

SET @mycur = CURSOR
FOR
SELECT * FROM @temp

OPEN @mycur

FETCH NEXT FROM @mycur INTO @id,@ParentNodeName,@NodeName,@NodeText

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
PRINT @id -- sample statements
PRINT  @ParentNodeName
PRINT  @NodeName
        SET @x.modify
        ('
            insert attribute status {sql:variable("@status")}
            as first
            into (/@ParentNodeName/@NodeName/child::*[position()=sql:variable("@status")])[1] 
        ')
FETCH NEXT FROM @mycur INTO  @id,@ParentNodeName,@NodeName,@NodeText
END

DEALLOCATE @mycur
```

Any idea why I am getting this error as query works fine if I manually insert path

Comment: What type and value is  `@status` ? That's not visible anywhere in your sample....

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with @ParentNodeName and @NodeName; the @ symbol is used refer to a variable in SQL, but it references an attribute in XML.  The .modify() method is attempting to insert a row at the root with an attribute chain, which is poorly formatted SQL, when it looks like you are trying to build a dynamic XML document.  You'll need to build a dynamic SQL statement which replaces the values of @ParentNodeName and @NodeName with their values from your temp table, something like:

```
SET @SQL = '        SET @x.modify 
        (''' 
            insert attribute status {sql:variable("@status")} 
            as first 
            into (/@ParentNodeName/@NodeName/child::*[position()=sql:variable("@status")])[1]  
        ''') 

SET @SQL = REPLACE(@SQL, '@ParentNodeName', @ParentNodeName)
SET @SQL = REPLACE(@SQL, '@NodeName', NodeName)

EXEC (@SQL)
```

untested.